# Include en una página de Wordpress generada por PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-plugin

Estoy intentanto desarrollar un plugin para Wordpress el cual me crea un post tipo página para mostrar una serie de resultados de la DB de un producto.
El problema me lo encuentro no en la creación de la página sino cuando quiero llamar mediante *include* o *require* un php externo, ya que la función que aplico es la de http://www.wpexplorer.com/create-wordpress-posts-pages-using-php/

```
 if ( ! function_exists( 'PostCreator' ) ) {

    function PostCreator(
        $name      = 'AUTO POST',
        $type      = 'post',
        $content   = 'DUMMY CONTENT',
        $category  = array(1,2),
        $template  = NULL,
        $author_id = '1',
        $status    = 'publish'
    ) {

        define( POST_NAME, $name );
        define( POST_TYPE, $type );
        define( POST_CONTENT, $content );
        define( POST_CATEGORY, $category );
        define( POST_TEMPLATE, '' );
        define( POST_AUTH_ID, $author_id );
        define( POST_STATUS, $status );

        if ( $type == 'page' ) {
            $post      = get_page_by_title( POST_NAME, 'OBJECT', $type );
            $post_id   = $post->ID;
            $post_data = get_page( $post_id );
            define( POST_TEMPLATE, $template );
        } else {
            $post      = get_page_by_title( POST_NAME, 'OBJECT', $type );
            $post_id   = $post->ID;
            $post_data = get_post( $post_id );
        }

        function hbt_create_post() {
            $post_data = array(
                'post_title'    => wp_strip_all_tags( POST_NAME ),
                'post_content'  => POST_CONTENT,
                'post_status'   => POST_STATUS,
                'post_type'     => POST_TYPE,
                'post_author'   => POST_AUTH_ID,
                'post_category' => POST_CATEGORY,
                'page_template' => POST_TEMPLATE
            );
            wp_insert_post( $post_data, $error_obj );
        }

        if ( ! isset( $post ) ) {
            add_action( 'admin_init', 'hbt_create_post' );
            return $error_obj;
        }

    }
}

/* All available options for PostCreator()

PostCreator( 'TITLE' , 'POST TYPE' , 'POST CONTENT' , 'POST CATEGORY' , 'TEMPLATE FILE NAME' , 'AUTHOR ID NUMBER' , 'POST STATUS');

TITLE - HTML Stripped Out. Simple String.
POST TYPE - Post type slug. Eg 'post' or 'page'. Custom Post Types are supported.
POST CONTENT - Content of the Post/Page. HTML allowed.
POST CATEGORY - An array of the integer ID's of the category/categories you want to link to your post
TEMPLATE FILE NAME - File name of the template. Only for Pages. In the format 'file_name.php'.
AUTHOR ID NUMBER - Integer value. Default is 1.
POST STATUS - Available options; [ 'draft' | 'publish' | 'pending'| 'future' | 'private' | custom registered status ]

If successful, PostCreator() returns nothing.
If there is an error PostCreator() returns a WP_error object.

*/

PostCreator( 'My Lorem Ipsum', 'page', 'With a sizable serving of Dolor. This was created using Harri Bell-Thomas\'s PostCreator function.' );
```

y no sé cómo hacer la llamada en

```
PostCreator( 'TITULO DE LA PAGINA', 'page', 'CONTENIDO: DONDE HACER EL INCLUDE' );
```

Es posible hacerlo des del mismo plugin o hay que editar la página directamente des del Dashboard de WP? Hay alguna otra manera?
Muchas gracias a todxs.

Answer (score -1):

> El problema me lo encuentro no en la creación de la página sino cuando
>   quiero llamar mediante include o require un php externo

No tenes que usar include o require. 
Por lo que veo en el código, el mismo se agrega en el functions.php del theme de wordpress.

> y no sé cómo hacer la llamada en
>
> PostCreator( 'TITULO DE LA PAGINA', 'page', 'CONTENIDO: DONDE HACER EL
>   INCLUDE' );

La llamada también va el functions.php.

La creación del contenido parece estar enlazada al hook admin_init que se dispara cuando entras al admin (Dashboard) de Wordpress.

Comment: Juan, tienes suficiente reputación para realizar comentarios, revisa [answer].

Comment: Hola @Jorgesys, que sería en lo que debería hacer foco como para corregirlo?

Comment: Esto no proporciona una respuesta a la pregunta. Para criticar o pedir aclaración a un autor, deja un comentario debajo de su publicación. - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/67602)

Comment: @toledano, no estoy criticando ni pidiendo aclaraciones. Igual voy a reformular la respuesta porque evidentemente genera alguna confusión.

Comment: De acuerdo: a través del **hook** _admin_init_ debería crear la llamada al contenido enlazando al post por ID?

Comment: El codigo ya tiene el hook creado, fijate al final de la clase. Como te decía este codigo que pegaste parece estar hecho para ejecutarse así, colocando todo el codigo en el archivo functions.pho que puede ser o no lo que vos estas queriendo.